# Button or Link That Changes Page in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe, hyperlink

I wish to make a link or button in a page that changes the page the iframe is on. It would be a local page:

> idreesinc.com/iframe.html

and you can see what I have already here:

> idreesinc.com/research

Help would be much appreciated as i have been looking for an answer for ages. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<script>
function setURL(url){
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
}
</script>
<iframe id="iframe" src="idreesinc.com/research.html" />
<input type="button" onclick="setURL('URLHere')" />
```

Answer (score 19):

You can simply make an link with its target to the iframe name as follows:

```
<iframe name="demo" src="example.php"></iframe>
```

Your link in the parent will be:

```
<a href="newpage.html" target="demo">Change Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a button inside a link with its target pointing to the iframe name:

```
<iframe name="demo" src="site1.html"></iframe>
<a href="site2.html" target="demo"><button>site2</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuery.

`$("#mybutton").click(function(){$("#myiframe").attr("src", "http://www.yahoo.com/")});​`

http://jsfiddle.net/ws2hm/1/

```
 #myiframe { width: 300px; height: 300px }

$("#mybutton").click(function(){$("#myiframe").attr("src", "http://www.yahoo.com/")});​

Text on main page
<button id="mybutton">Swap</button>
<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://www.bing.com/"></iframe>​
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont have jquery. Thanks though!