# Using CSS buttons to control iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

Update #3: Dan and Xero, your answers include JS. I cant use JS for a number of unexplainable reasons. Nor can I use JQuery. The tags on this question were updated in case they caused some confusion.

I am redesigning my website and have copied this basic CSS navbar code from a HTML tutorial website:

CODE:

```
<head>
<style> 
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:100px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#0066CC;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:lowercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#003399;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

But the issue is that I want these buttons in the navbar to control the iframe src below it.
I found this on StackOverflow but I do not know how to implent this:
[Button or Link That Changes Page in Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524990/button-or-link-that-changes-page-in-iframe)

It will all be local (on the same web server) and I am trying to avoid JavaScript/JQuery.
Can it be done this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you do not want a JS solution you could use CSS to hide all the iframes unless one is selected. It will be more work for you to try and style thing appropriately since the sections need to be nested but it's a solution without js.

the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.collapse > * + *{
  display:none;
}
.collapse > *{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.collapse:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.collapse:focus > * + *{
  display:block; 
}
</style>
```

The HTML

```
  <div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
     <h2 >Collapse 1 +</h2>
    <iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
     <h2 >Collapse 2 +</h2>
      <iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually, this is the best solution of them all! Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

You would do it pretty much the same way in the link you provided

```
<script>
function iFrame(url){
    document.getElementByTagName('iframe').src = url;
}
</script>
```

Then just apply it to the buttons:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#home" onclick="iFrame('URLHERE')">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news" onclick="iFrame('URLHERE')">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact" onclick="iFrame('URLHERE')">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about" onclick="iFrame('URLHERE')">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

don't forget to put in the iframe.

If I didn't answer your question right. Notify me, and I will correct it.

Comment: But isnt there a way to do it without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // dynamically change the iframe src.
    function load_iframe( url ) {
        // set variable with the iframe id
        var $iframe = $('#dynamic_frame');
        // make certain the iframe is available
        if ( $iframe.length ) {
            $iframe.attr('src',url);   
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Notice that you'll need to change the link urls to your own fully qualified urls.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://yoursite.com#anyhash" onclick="return load_iframe(this.href);" >Your Site</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apple.com#anyhash" onclick="return load_iframe(this.href);" >Apple.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://microsoft.com#anyhash" onclick="return load_iframe(this.href);" >Microsoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com#anyhash" onclick="return load_iframe(this.href);">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

Drop the iframe in your page:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" id="dynamic_frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: But this uses JScript. Thanks but i need to avoid it, long story.

Comment: Not dynamically. You could create a new page for each unique iframe and link to each.

Comment: Wont work. It doesnt follow the plan. But on second thoughts, i could have 2 versions of my site, one with JS and one without, where the one without follows your 'link' idea.
Im aiming for the parent page to not refresh at all, but to make the iframe refresh only when needed to (i.e, using navbar).

Thanks! I shall vote as answer!